# show distinct id's of all professors who taught at least 2 courses in the same semester

Tags: sql, database

I am having a little trouble doing this one SQL homework problem and have tried multiple different attempts but keep getting the same wrong answer. I am not sure what i'm missing, if anyone can please help me out that'd be really nice! :)

Question: **Show distinct id's of all professors who taught at least 2 courses in the same semester**

Here are the tables given to us:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PROFESSOR;  
CREATE TABLE PROFESSOR (  
    Id   VARCHAR (9),   
    Name    VARCHAR (32),  
    DepartmentId  VARCHAR (3),   
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),  
    FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentId) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Id)  
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO PROFESSOR VALUES  
('P01', 'Rao',      'CSC'),  
('P02', 'Mitra',    'CSC'),  
('P03', 'Smith',    'MTH'),  
('P04', 'Miller',   'MTH'),  
('P05', 'Abwender', 'PSH'),  
('P06', 'Speed',    'PSH');  

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEACHING_ASSIGNMENT;  
CREATE TABLE TEACHING_ASSIGNMENT (  
    ProfessorId VARCHAR (9), -- Department Code may be different   
    CourseCode  VARCHAR (6), -- This is like CIS422  
    Semester    VARCHAR (16),-- This is like Fall 2016  
    Section     VARCHAR (3), -- This is like 01  
    PRIMARY KEY (ProfessorId, CourseCode, Semester, Section),  
    FOREIGN KEY (ProfessorId) REFERENCES PROFESSOR (Id),  
    FOREIGN KEY (CourseCode)  REFERENCES COURSE (CourseCode)  
)ENGINE=INNODB;  


INSERT INTO TEACHING_ASSIGNMENT VALUES  
('P01', 'CSC203', 'Fall 2015', '01'),  
('P02', 'CIS202', 'Fall 2015', '01'),  
('P03', 'MTH201', 'Fall 2015', '01'),  
('P04', 'MTH281', 'Fall 2015', '01'),  
('P05', 'PSH110', 'Fall 2015', '01'),  
('P06', 'PSH201', 'Fall 2015', '01'),  
('P01', 'CIS202', 'Fall 2015', '02'),  
('P03', 'CSC203', 'Spring 2016', '01'),  
('P02', 'CIS202', 'Spring 2016', '01'),  
('P03', 'MTH201', 'Spring 2016', '01'),  
('P04', 'MTH281', 'Spring 2016', '01'),  
('P05', 'PSH110', 'Spring 2016', '01'),  
('P06', 'PSH201', 'Spring 2016', '01'),  
('P01', 'CIS202', 'Spring 2016', '02');
```

My SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM PROFESSOR
WHERE Id IN
    (SELECT ProfessorId
     FROM TEACHING_ASSIGNMENT
     GROUP BY Semester
     HAVING COUNT() >= 2);
```

The answer i get: P01

But the right answer should be P01 AND P03.

Comment: Can you please add your table code to the question itself rather than simply including it as an image? That makes it much easier for us to debug :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Hi! I did try to do that at first but the formatting looked really messy on here. So that's why i just took a screenshot of the tables instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No subquery is necessary:

```
SELECT ProfessorId
FROM TEACHING_ASSIGNMENT
GROUP BY Semester, ProfessorId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: yes, you're right. I still get the right answer. thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: That's right but the important thing here is that the query is also grouped by `ProfessorId`

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` should include `ProfessorId` cause you are counting number of courses taught by a professor in a semester. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM PROFESSOR
WHERE Id IN
    (SELECT ProfessorId
     FROM TEACHING_ASSIGNMENT
     GROUP BY Semester, ProfessorId
     HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2);
```

Comment: wowww i cant believe i didn't think of that. It worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query, i checked it after creating a new Table.

```
select Courses.ProfessorId, count(*) from Cou_Pro Courses 
group by Courses.ProfessorId, Courses.Semester having
count(Courses.ProfessorId) > 1
```